# Array Merge trouble

Tags: php, cakephp, array-merge

Sorry, have made the title make it sound complicated.

Am looking to merge an array into an already created massive multidimensional array.

First idea... is it possible to create a sub array as an array(); while looping the array your creating into?

e.g

```
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $record['AddedContent']['Comments'] = array(); //doesn't currently exist
            foreach ($comments as $comment) {
                if($record['AddedContent']['id'] = $comment['content_id']){
                    array_push($record['AddedContent']['Comments'], $comment);

                }
            }
        }
```

Here Comments is the little array i want to join to records (big array)

the arrays are as follows:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [SubscribedToProfile] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [company_name] => 
                [picture_filename] => 
            )

        [AddedContent] => Array
            (
                [text] => 
                [file_location] => 
                [content_type_id] => 4
                [file_name] => IxnAvLKMtIU
                [id] => 87
            )

    )
```

the comments array is:

```
Array
 (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [ContentComment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [content_id] => 87
                [text] => jhbuoijniknb

                [created] => 2013-10-21 13:08:12
                [user_id] => 2097
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ContentComment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [content_id] => 88
                [text] => gfrgfrtegvrtegvrtgvrtvtrgv
                [created] => 2013-10-21 13:08:12
                [user_id] => 2097
            )
    )
```

)

and i need it to be:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [SubscribedToProfile] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [company_name] => 
                [picture_filename] => 
            )

        [AddedContent] => Array
            (
                [text] => 
                [file_location] => 
                [content_type_id] => 4
                [file_name] => IxnAvLKMtIU
                [id] => 87
                [comments] => Array
                            (
                            [0] => Array
                                    (
                                     [id] => 2
                                     [content_id] => 87
                                     [text] => fderwcfrvfcerwfvrev
                                     [created] => 2013-10-21 13:05:58
                                     [user_id] => 2097
                                     )
                             [1] => Array
                                    (
                                     [id] => 3
                                     [content_id] => 87
                                     [text] => jhbuoijniknb
                                     [created] => 2013-10-21 13:08:12
                                     [user_id] => 2097
                                     )
                                )
                    )
            )
```

I need to loop through bpth arrays though as I need to conditionally join htem see where the ID is 87 (in this example) and the content ID is 87.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is here.

```
foreach ($records as $key=>$record) {
    $array = array();
    if($key=='AddedContent') {
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            if($record['id'] == $comment["ContentComment"]['content_id']){
                array_push($array, $comment["ContentComment"]);
            }
        }
        $records[$key]['comments'] = $array;
    }
}
```